# What figure should most logically follow the series?

Tags: visual

The square is divided into 9 squares (3x3) and it changes from left to right, following some rule. The right hand column shows the answer choices.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also believe the answer to be

> [image]

But I have a different reason.

> [image] 
> I've color coated this to make it easier. Red and Green both cycle around the edges in a counter-clockwise motion. Yellow goes left, middle, right, middle, and presumably left again like it's "walking" back and forth. Blue, like Yellow, is going back and forth but on a diagonal. Middle, Upper-Right, Middle, Lower-Left, presumably middle again. Each color has a cyclical movement as if it were pacing (either back and forth or in a circle).

This would mean that the NEXT next would be

> [image] 
> Which is exactly the same as the second image in the pattern except Red and Green are backwards.

Comment: I believe this is the accepted reason because there were previous instructions saying the changes are primarily movements of the shapes.

Comment: Well done! And welcome to Puzzling beta!

Answer (score 3):

I would say this one

> [image]

Because

> Every other picture, starting with the first one, in the sequence is the same picture, just a mirrored version

For a bonus guess the picture after that might look like

> [image]

Because

> Every other starting with the second picture is the same picture, rotated clockwise 90 degrees then mirrored (Makes sense to me at least!)

Comment: what do you mean by odd number?

Comment: Like Picture 1 = 1, picture 2 = 2... I guess that is really poorly worded. I'll change that.